# How can I identify Ethernet adapters on GNU/Linux using C

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I am updating some software which uses a hardcoded network iface (`eth0`) for various purposes. What I'd like to do is detect which ethernet interface would be first. I understand the changes with systemd and how `eth0` may very well not exist on these systems with the new naming scheme. So what I am trying to do is run through all the interfaces and detect the ethernet adapters. I would like to avoid `lo`, `tun` and other virtual devices. So far so good with this code:

```
char* getMainEthernetIfaceName() {
    char *name = NULL;
    struct if_nameindex *ifacenames = if_nameindex(), *idx;

    if (!ifacenames) return name;

    for (idx = ifacenames; !(!idx->if_index && !idx->if_name); ++idx) {
        char path[256];
        sprintf(path,"/sys/class/net/%s/type", idx->if_name);
        FILE *fp = fopen(path, "re");
        if (fp) {
            int type;
            if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &type) == 1) {
                if (type == ARPHRD_ETHER) {
                    name = malloc(IF_NAMESIZE);
                    strncpy(name, idx->if_name, IF_NAMESIZE-1);

                    fclose(fp);
                    break;
                }
            }
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }

    if_freenameindex(ifacenames);
    return name;
}
```

However, my test still detects `pan0` as valid since it's type is `ARPHRD_ETHER`.

First part of the question, is it sensible to use `sysfs` to identify this as an ethernet device?

Second part, if so, how can I rule out Bluetooth PAN and potentially other devices as being chosen when I only want ethernet adapters?

Please note, this needs to work on both systemd and non-systemd systems, and I would rather avoid inferring the type from the iface name (no `strncmp(if_name, "eth", 3) == 0`, `strncmp(if_name, "en", 2) == 0`, and the sort for forwards compatibility and manually configured naming.)

Comment: Look at [`getifaddrs()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) for enumerating local interfaces and getting their names, capabilities, and local addresses.

Comment: Looks like dreadful C++ code.

Comment: @Remy `name = new char[IF_NAMESIZE];`

Comment: @RemyLebeau `safe::strcpy` is C++. The rest could be either, although it's not idiomatic C++.

Comment: "sysfs" is great ... but it might *NOT* the easiest way to identify "ethernet devices".  Alternative suggestion (one of many): `lspci | grep -i eth` (e.g. from a [popen()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) call).

Comment: `sizeof(name)` is wrong. That's the size of the pointer, not `IF_NAMESIZE`

Comment: It's a 20+ year codebase moving to C++ from C, so most adheres to C.

Comment: Changed the example to adhere to C and recategorized.

Comment: virtual interfaces can also be type 1.  Check `speed` for a reasonable value (10-40000)

Comment: My current machine has 3 ethernet adapters, which one do you want to use? One on the laptop itself, one on the docking station, and another one is a USB adapter.